# Javascript listening for data changes & trigger reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a server sent event in PHP that displays inventory information client side and updates in real time. That part works great. The challenge is that I want to trigger a reload when the inventory = 0. Note: I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Here's my code:

```
var source = new EventSource('listener.php');
source.onmessage = function(msg) {
document.getElementById('inv').innerHTML = msg.data; 
};

source.addEventListener('msg', onMessageHandler,false);

function onMessageHandler(msg) {
var inventory = msg.data;
};

// Trying to Fire Something like this //
//if (inventory = 0) {
//setTimeout(function() {    
//location.reload(true) 
//},5000);
```

Thanks for any suggestions : )

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Is it going inside of if condition if inventory value '0'?

Comment: `if (inventory = 0)` -> `if (inventory == 0)` or `if (inventory === 0)`

Comment: Changed to if (inventory === 0) and no errors in console.

Comment: Checked all and if (inventory == 0) is the right way. The code order is changed. Works now : )

Comment: Thank you @Andeas for looking at that : )

Answer (score 0):

Watch the scoping:

```
var source = new EventSource('listener.php');
source.onmessage = function(msg) {
  document.getElementById('inv').innerHTML = msg.data; 
};

source.addEventListener('msg', onMessageHandler,false);

function onMessageHandler(msg) {
var inventory = msg.data;
 if (inventory === 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload(true);
    }, 5000);
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried your corrected code. It still won't fire, though. Most likely some issue with jQuery Mobile? Sorry if I forgot to mention that in OP.

Comment: Thank you @Gearoid. You pointed me in the right direction toward a solution. Much appreciation : )

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. Both helped tremendously. This is what worked for me in the event any others ever have a similar challenge:

```
var source = new EventSource('listener.php');
source.onmessage = function(msg) {
  document.getElementById('inv').innerHTML = msg.data;
  console.log(msg.data);
  var x = msg.data;
  if (x == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(true);
      // Or any of the 1000's of other ways to reload
    }, 1000);
  }
};

source.addEventListener('msg', onMessageHandler,false);

function onMessageHandler(msg) {
  var inventory = msg.data;
};
```